# Is there a way to enable selection when TextInput is set to editable=false

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm wondering if any of you know of a way to make `TextInput` selectable while the `editable={false}`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the current behavior of React Native
you can `fake` `TextInput` in your case with `Text` and use `selectable` props
https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#selectable

or something like this

```
this.state.editable ? <TextInput /> : <Text selectable={true} />;
```